# AWS SES SMTP not accepting TLSv1.3

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, tls1.3

I have a Java application that connects to the AWS SMTP server to send emails. We upgraded to Java 17 and wanted the default TLS version to be 1.3. The application is using JavaMail and we set the protocol value using the below command

```
javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols","TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2");
```

Even though my application has TLSv1.3 enabled, the emails that are sent by AWS Simple Email Service (SES) are using TLSv1.2.

I have verified the application supports TLSv1.3 by using the following code in the application

```
try{

     logger.info("List of supported SSL Protocols - " + 
     Arrays.toString(SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()));
}
catch (Exception e){
   logger.error("SSLContext Error" + e);
}
```

The output for the above snippet is

```
[TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, SSLv3, SSLv2Hello]
```

I used openssl command to verify whether I can connect to AWS SMTP server using TLSv1.3 using the following command

```
openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587 -tls1_3
```

I got the below error

```
4582575616:error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 70
```

But tls1_2 works

```
openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587 -tls1_2
```

Output

```
depth=2 C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon RSA 2048 M01
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
verify return:1
250 Ok
451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.
```

I do not see any configuration in AWS console in SES to accept TLSv1.3. Any reason this doesn't work? Is it possible to use TLSv1.3? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Any reason this doesn't work?" - uh, because it's not supported yet? Your requirements need to change as there is zero reason to require 1.3 at this point.

Comment: @stdunbar This is from the documentation `For STARTTLS connections, Amazon SES supports TLS 1.2, TLS 1.3, and SSLv2Hello.` 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/security-protocols.html

Comment: But [this post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tls-1-2-required-for-aws-endpoints/) and [this one](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tls-1-2-required-for-aws-endpoints/) - the last posted about 1.5 months ago - indicate that this is all very much still in progress.  TLS 1.2 is a fully supported protocol and no publicly facing service will have deprecated it yet.